# pyTelegramBotAPI не найден модуль telebot Ошибка

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

У меня возникаєт ошибка при запуске кода пишет што не найлен модуль telebot помогите пожалуста.

Comment: Я уже решил проблему Спасибо всем и сидите дома.

Comment: Как решили? Пожалуйста, поделитесь этим с нами. Возможно, это поможет кому-то в будущем.

Answer (score -1):

Я ето решил я начал запускать програму не через консоль прописуючи путь к програме а через Python Shell а перед етим переустановил модкль